# 'affected by Lycanthrophy' (BMC) is functionally the same as 'appear as wolfpack to Seer'?

Tags: werewolv.es

Cult Leader and Blood Priest have abilities that only work on people affected by Lycanthrophy. Is Lycanthrophy only tied to certain roles (Lycans, MWs, Wolfpack) and the Sanguine Horn, or does carrying a Wolf Pelt also confer 'Lycanthrophy' status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at the moment several different modifiers which make you look like a wolf.

1. Being a Lycan or Maple Wolf
2. Being affected by lycanthropy due to being BMC or being afflicted by the Sanguine Horn
3. Having a wolf pelt

All three are different statuses, BMC only works on 2) lycanthropy. 1) and 3) have no effect on the ritual, so only players afflicted by 2) can be successfully rited and thus recruited.